# How is it possible to delete the listed files in php?

Tags: php

How can I delete all the listed files using PHP?  As shown in the code, it displays all the files in the folder with a "Delete" button next to each one... but how can I use the `unlink` function to delete the particular file when its "Delete" button is clicked?

```
function Deletion()
{
    $files1 = scandir('upload/');
    $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..');
    foreach ($files1 as $file1) 
    {
        if(!in_array($file1, $ignore)) 
        {
            echo '<div>
                   <img src="upload/' . $file1 . '" height="50px" width="50px" />
                   <input type="button" value="Delete" name="del"/><br>
                   <a href="upload/'.$loca.'/'.$file1.'" target="_BLANK"
                     style=" font-size:12px; color:#333;"><p >'.$file1.'</p></a>
                  </div>';         
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to perform an action on the server side when the button is clicked. Use AJAX to make a GET request to a page on your server with the filename as a parameter and then run unlink on the GET parameter. I generally suggest jQuery to beginners in AJAX.

JavaScript:

```
jQuery.post("delete.php", {file: "dont-want.php"})
```

PHP:

```
unlink($_POST["file"])
```

Comment: Using `GET` to delete files is rather iffy.  `GET` should not have visible side effects.  (Consider what would happen if a spider ever got a hold of a bunch of delete links.)  You might use `POST` (or if you wanted to be a purist, `DELETE`) instead, as those are intended for actions that involve more than just retrieving stuff.

Comment: True, I really should be more semantic with my request types.

Comment: Don't forget to check the filename and/or user authorization before deleting. You don't want a hacker to be able to do something like `jQuery.post("delete.php", {file: "../index.php"})` ;)